# How to trigger a function when scrolled to a specific point in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I am not looking for a `ngInfiniteScroll` solution (I don't want to use jQuery).

My page is divided into three sections

```
<section id="A" ng-init="initA()">
 <!-- Content A -->
</section>

<section id="B" ng-init="initB()">
 <!-- Content B -->
</section>

<section id="C" ng-init="initC()">
 <!-- Content C -->
</section>
```

How do I trigger the functions `initA(), init(B), init(C)` when the user scrolls down to the relevant section? That is, upon page load, nothing is loaded. But then once the user starts scrolling down the `initX()` is being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a directive for that.
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6683ppmx/1/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('dSec', function($window) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
        scope.initialScroll[attr.id] = elm.prop('offsetTop');
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
             if (this.pageYOffset >= scope.initialScroll[attr.id]
                    && !scope.hitScroll[attr.id]) {
                 console.log("Scroll to --> ", attr.id);
                 scope.hitScroll[attr.id] = true;
             }
        });
    }
  };
});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.initialScroll = {};
    $scope.hitScroll = {};
}
```

Comment: Not working, it fires it immediately, despite that I scrolled to the section

Comment: It fires immediately for section A because it is at the top already. When you scroll down to B/C, it is fired for B/C accordingly.

Comment: But I am not sure how you capture the event? Like how do I trigger the the function upon scroll?

Comment: We bind scroll event to window element. When user scrolls, bind event fires each time; and we check window object's scroll position (this.pageYOffset) against our section's initial top position. If you want to trigger some code every time the section hits by scroll, then you should remove $scope.hitScroll and relevant code.

Comment: @KursadGulseven can u give the answer for angular version >=2